# Finding the sum of a Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations

> The function $\phi(x) = x$ on the interval $[-l,l]$ has the Fourier series
>   $$x = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{l} \right) + \frac{1}{3}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l} \right) - \ldots \right)$$
>   a.) Set $x = \frac{l}{2}$ to find the sum of the series
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \ldots$$

Attempted solution - If I understand this correctly we are asked to find the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \ldots$$

I do not remember how to evaluate this infinite alternate series, the answer is suppose to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ evaluated at $x = 1$, so the answer is $\arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4} $

For finding this Taylor Series, let's expand about $x=0$ (technically, this is a MacLaurin Series).

$\arctan(0) =0$

$\arctan^{(1)}(0) = (1+0^2)^{-1} = 1$

$\arctan^{(2)}(0)'' = -2*0*(1+0^2)^{-2} = 0$

$\arctan^{(3)}(0) = (6*0^2-2)(1+0^2)^{-3}= -2$

$\arctan^{(4)}(0) = -24*0*(0^2-1)((1+0^2)^{-4} = 0$

$\arctan^{(5)} (0) = 24(5*0^4-10*0^2+1)(1+0^2)^-5 = 24$

This tells us $f^{(2n+1)}(0) = (-1)^{n} (2n)! $ and $f^{(2n)}(0) = 0$
Therefore,

$$\arctan(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$

Alternatively,

$1 - \sin(x)$ is an entire function, so by Weierstrass Factorization Theorem, it can be written as a product of its zeros, which occur at $x = \frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2} $ and $\frac{-(4n+3) \pi}{2}$ (note, these are double roots)

Equating this to its Taylor series of $1 - \sin(x)$, we get

$$1 - x + O(x^3) = (1 - \frac{2}{\pi}x)^2(1 + \frac{2}{3\pi}x)^2(1 - \frac{2}{5\pi}x)^2(1 + \frac{2}{7\pi}x)^2... $$

Expanding the RHS

$$x - O(x^3) = \frac{4}{\pi}x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}-O(x^2)$$

Equating $x$ terms,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: I understand what I seem to be having trouble with is simply finding the taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ at $x = a$ for example

Comment: Could you try to explain why it is the taylor series of $\arctan(x)$

Comment: @Wolfgang-1: I have just updated it to explain.